# What is the most idiomatic way to show a retry button when the receiveError event happens on a WebViewClient?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-event

I would like to show a retry button when my application cannot load a page. As far as I understand, whenever this happens, the `onReceiveError()` method on `WebViewClient` is called.

I have a piece of code that does an animation. It makes a button visible and animates the `y` property of it until it reaches the middle of the screen. However, I would like to be able to fire this piece of code in the `onReceiveError()` method, and animate the button down and make it invisible when `onPageFinished()` happens.

My problem is not with the animation bit of the code. My problem is in where to put it. I can't put the animation code inside the `WebViewClient` since as I said above, I have to reach through the `WebView` to its parent activity, and animate a `Button` defined on that activity. This violates every object-oriented best practice I'm aware of, so I have a bad feeling about it. However, I don't know where else I can put it. I'm looking for a best practice defined by the community on code like this, where a dependency of a view (i.e. `WebViewClient`) needs to change something on an activity.

I'm new to Android development, so please be gentle.

Comment: This would be the same as any other view animation in Android, where the view you want to animate is positioned above the WebView on the z axis when visible.  Have you searched for anything on the topic of view animation yet?

Comment: Yes. My issue is not the bit about animation; I know how to animate. I don't know "where" to animate. That is, it doesn't feel right to put the animation code inside `WebViewClient` since I'm reaching through another object (i.e. `WebView`) to its activity and animating one of its views (i.e. the `Button`). Where should I put the animation code? I'm guessing I should put it in the `MainActivity` and have it listen to the `onReceiveError` event, but I'm not sure how to do it, or if it is even possible, or whether it is idiomatic.

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make it clearer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can animate a view in the same view hierarchy as the WebView, not inside the WebView.  Just be sure to place it on top of the WebView so it can be seen.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use `view.getParent().findViewById(R.id.btn_retry).animate().y(...)`? If I have to do this, I'm reaching through the `Webview` to its parent, which is the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Just find the view by its ID and work with it from there.  Nothing unusual about that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please create an answer and give me a code example? The code I'm looking for is the code inside a concrete  `WebViewClient` implementation that overrides `onReceiveError`.